# How to bind Telerik MVC grid to DropDownList via Ajax?

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to bind a dropdownlist to a telerik grid, so that when the value of the dropdownlist changes the grid will update via ajax to show results. Here is my code so far:

IndexView:

<% Html.RenderPartial("AptProfileFilter"); %>
    <%= Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.profiles)//Initial Server Binding
             .Name("Profiles").DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
             .Ajax()
             .Update("_AjaxBinding", "AptProfile", new {id = (string)ViewData["BuildingID"]}))
             .Columns(columns =>
                {
               columns.Bound(p => p.AptProfileID).Width(100);
               columns.Bound(p => p.Apartment.Building.Complex.Name).Width(100);
               columns.Bound(p => p.Apartment.Building.BuildingID).Width(100);
               columns.Bound(p => p.Apartment.AptRate).Width(100);
                })
              .Pageable()
              .Sortable()

I used FireBug to determine that the correct data is being posted( after selecting a element from my dropdownlist)
back to the Data collection in the GridModel class, but I do not understand why it is not updating the Grid with this new data?

I am very new to web development. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been wrestling with this too. take a look at the link below (bottom of comment), in which I asked the same type of question. In my case, I managed to get this working, but still have some questions about HOW I got it working. Anyway, I hope this helps ... Also, in my case, I'm using Razor views, which you might not be, based upon you use of the <% operators ... [Telerik MVC Grid: How to use DropDownList in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087546/telerik-mvc-grid-how-to-use-dropdownlist-in-a-column/7101879#7101879)